# Repetir misma select sql para diferentes fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito ejecutar una misma select en SQL Server para diferentes fechas.
Ahora mismo lo que hago es declarar dos variable fecha inicio y fecha fin.  Q se corresponden con el primer y último día del mes que necesito. Por ejemplo enero, luego cambio las fechas para el mes de febrero y vuelvo  a ejecutar, repito el proceso con marzo y así sucesivamente.

```
    DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20200101'
    DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20200201'
    -- fechas para obtener datos de enero

    SELECT COUNT (*) 
    FROM tabla
    WHERE SISTEMA = 0
    ANDFEC_ESTADO_PASO BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN
```

Habría alguna manera de hacer esto sin tener que editar la fechas para cada ejecución. Introducir todas fechas la primera vez y poder ejecutarlo de una sola vez??

Comment: siempre agrupas por meses completos o los períodos varían?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agrupar por año y mes de FEC_ESTADO_PASO y con esto obtendrás lo que planteas:

```
DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20200101'
    DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20210101'

    SELECT datepart(year,FEC_ESTADO_PASO) año,datepart(month,FEC_ESTADO_PASO) MES,COUNT (*) 
    FROM tabla
    WHERE SISTEMA = 0
    AND FEC_ESTADO_PASO BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN
    group by datepart(year,FEC_ESTADO_PASO),datepart(month,FEC_ESTADO_PASO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Siempre depende de como deseas obtener la salida real. Si lo que necesitas es una única columna con el valor, y varias filas con los datos de los meses involucrados, puedes hacer algo similar a esto:

```
create table dbo.tabla (id int identity(1,1), FEC_ESTADO_PASO datetime, sistema tinyint)
go
;with r as (
    Select n
    from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))Tbl(n)
    ), r2 as 
    (Select r.n from r cross join r as b 
    ), r3 as
    (Select r2.n from r2 cross join r2 as b 
    ), num as (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by r3.n) as row from r3
    )
    Insert into dbo.tabla (FEC_ESTADO_PASO, sistema)
    Select dateadd(hour,num.row, '20200101'),0 from num;
go
```

Ahora tenemos una tabla poblada con datos de ejemplo.

```
DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20200101'
DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20200301'


;with c as (
    Select mes
    From (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))Tbl(mes)
    ), r as(    
Select Cout (*) as veces, DatePart(month,FEC_ESTADO_PASO)  as mes
    From dbo.tabla
    Where SISTEMA = 0
         And FEC_ESTADO_PASO > @FEC_INICIO 
         And FEC_ESTADO_PASO <= @FEC_FIN
    Group by DatePart(month,FEC_ESTADO_PASO)
) 
Select isnull(r.veces,0)
    from c left join r on c.mes = r.mes
    Where c.mes < datePart(month,@fec_fin)
        and c.mes >= datePart(month,@fec_inicio)
    order by c.mes
```

[image: Resultado]

Cosas a tener en cuenta. Para obtener enero y febrero, le pasamos como fecha de corte el primer día del mes siguiente, para no perder ningún dato del último día del mes.

[Datetime sin perder datos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/11/datetime-where-sin-perder-datos/)

Esta manera solo sirve para extraer datos por meses y no años, por tanto los años, se limitan en los parámetros de entrada.

Si le pasas como parámetro 4 meses ('20200301','20200701') te devolverá las cuatro filas correspondientes a los meses solicitados.

[image: Resultado 2]

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/#more-224)